# Principal curvatures and directions of a polynomial surface

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Given a polynomial surface $M =\{(x,y,z): z = p(x,y))\}$ where $p(x,y)$ is a polynomial. I want compute the principal curvatures and directions at some point in $M$. But I do not have idea to compute the principal directions.

For the part of principal curvatures, I can formulate $E、F、G、L、M、N、W$, which are coefficients in first and second fundamental form, in function of $p,p_x,p_{xx},p_y,p_{yy},p_{xy}$. Then the Mean curvature and Gaussian curvature can be evaluate by 
$$
H = \frac{-1}{2}(EN - 2FM + GL)/W^2 \\
K = (LN - M^2)/W^2~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$$
Therefore, the principal curvatures can be formulated in function of $p,p_x,p_{xx},p_y,p_{yy},y_{xy}$ by 
$$
\kappa_1 = H - \sqrt{H^2 - K}\\
\kappa_2 = H + \sqrt{H^2 - K}
$$
for any point in surface $M$.

But now I do not have idea to compute the principal directions corresponding to $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$. Should I compute them by solving eigenvector of shape operator $S$? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should compute the eigenvectors of the shape operator. Keep in mind you already know the eigenvalues, that's what the principal curvatures are. You can use the Weingarten equations to compute the shape operator in terms of the first and second fundamental form.

Comment: How could I do that?  I am so confusing about the shape operator $S$.

Comment: The best way to do that is to use the Weingarten equations, given here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces#Shape_operator which can be found from the first and second fundamental forms.

Comment: Why the shape operator is not a 3 by 3 matrix in wiki page?  I think that the shape operator is a mapping form $R^3$ to $R^3$. I am so confusing...

Comment: The shape operator should be thought of as mapping the tangent plane of your surface to the tangent plane of the sphere. Although both sit inside $\mathbb{R}^3$ they are both two dimensional.

Comment: I use the formula of shape operator $S$ in wiki and compute the solution of $ (S - \kappa_i I)v = 0$, then I can get two 2 dimensional vectors $v = (v_1,v_2)$ corresponding $\kappa$. But our space is 3 dimensional, the principal direction must be 3D vector. Where is my mistake

Comment: The results you are getting are the components of the vectors with respect to the basis $\sigma_u,\sigma_v$ (the derivatives of your parametrization) for the tangent plane. You can find the vectors in the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by expanding them as $v_1\sigma_u + v_2\sigma_v$.

Comment: Can you explain the basis $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_v$ for me? I still not understanding all the details. Thank you. For an example, a ellipsoid $z(x,y) = \sqrt{1 -  x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2}$. I can get $S$ w.r.t fundamental form and the vector $v$, but what are the basis $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_v$ you said?

Comment: Just $(1,0,z_x)$ and $(0,1,z_y)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56413/discussion-between-phunfd-and-sinoky).